# Using Extract Data tool without compressing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, extract

I am looking for a way to either use the Extract Data tool within ArcMap without it compressing the files into a .zip at the end, or a way for the Clip tool to have a way to select multiple feature classes (see screenshot). The goal is to put this into ModelBuilder so that I can automate a process. However my knowledge concerning Python and inserting/editing scripts is limited to none and I know of no other way to achieve the results without scripting/adjusting.

[image: Example of what I am looking for in the clip tool.]

[image: Modelbuilder example]

Comment: Extract Data's other name is "Zip-n-Ship". Zipping is its fundamental purpose. It should be easy enough to write a tiny script that just exports data.

Comment: Perhaps using something like feature-class-to-feature-class or copy features.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please provide solutions to your own problem as a detailed answer to your question rather than as a brief statement within your question.

Answer (score 1):

Link how to implement this script into ModelBuilder.
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env


arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.env.workspace


clip_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fc_list:
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, clip_features, fc +'_clipped')
```

Comment: I should've specified that I am looking for a way to implement this into modelbuilder to automate a process. I apologise for that, would it be possible to implement this script as a tool within modelbuilder?

Comment: I edited my post, script is ready for MB. just read article how to implement this.

Comment: This is helping a lot! Thanks so far! I have another issue arising though, my feature classes come from all over the place and have been dragged into the TOC. If I understand correctly, the "fc_list" takes a list of feature classes from a single location, is it possible to target the TOC instead? (excluding the clip mask). I have tried looking for the code for this, but I have trouble finding it.

Comment: I think it is, but still you need to  tell me if you are using arcmap or arcgis pro.

Comment: Ah, I apologize, I am using Arcmap version 10.3.1 at the moment. The reason I don't want the "extract tool" to zip is because I want it to do something else in beforehand, I will add a screenshot of my MB, hopefuly it will add some more usefull information of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by, rather than using a multi-select clip, using iterate within the ArcMap MB only tools. This cycles through all the feature classes within a location, this means the users will have to put all their files into a selected GDB.